# Change language in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, language-support

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 with daily builds and updated a long the road until now... But one thing that never change is the language settings. I prefer Swedish as default language in menus and settings but even if I uninstall all languages but Swedish I just get english in all menues. What can I do to get Swedish in the menues, I have tried to uninstall all languages and reinstall but still just english..?

Answer (score 1):

`System Settings > Language Support > Languages`. You should have a list of your installed languages. By dragging and dropping re-order the list so that Swedish is on the first place. Afterwards, if you wish, you can click `Apply system-wide`, and also set things up under the `Regional Formats` tab.

Please note that even if you do all this, you'll have Swedish translated strings only if the translation exists. If any Swedish translations are missing, you'll get English strings instead.

Comment: does anybody know how to do it from cli?

Comment: answering my own question, `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8` seems to do the job.